# What is the proper usage of the windows tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2081/unable-to-switch-between-windows) today. The question is apparently about workspaces, but is a bit unclear on that. In any case, it used the "[windows](https://askubuntu.com/tagged/windows)" tag with a different meaning than the other questions using that tag.

All the other questions so tagged refer to the operating system but [the question in discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2081/unable-to-switch-between-windows) does not. I'm not sure what the solution is, but it seems incorrect to have questions use the same tag but apparently using different definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word means both things. Let it lie.

If you attempt to split it to `windows` and `ms-windows` you have two side-effects:

- You spend more time retagging things than directly helping people.
- You make it harder for people to search things externally. Who is going to put "ms-windows" into Google when they mean Windows?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I just wanted to see if overlapping tags (there are a few different ones) was an issue for anyone else and I thought "windows" was a good choice to hang a discussion on.

Comment: well.. a window in a GUI is automatically a widget. I would call ms-windows windows, and the UI window a widget if that is even necessary to tag at all.

Comment: what about Microsoft to replace Windows and windows to be, well windows. It's unfair that a corporation has taken a common word out of vocabulary because it's a product.

Comment: @txwikinger When you say widget, I think of micro-applications, applets, desktop widgets et al. A window is a window because it's a definite space in a window manager.

Comment: Searching Google for "windows" will match "ms-windows". Also I imagine the main text of the question would mention "Windows" as well as perhaps the title.

Answer (score 10):

Let's blacklist the [windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag (prevent anyone from using it) because it's too ambiguous. Instead:

1. Use [window-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-management) for the 'GUI object' (instead of [windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window))
2. Use the already heavily used [windows-xp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp), [vista](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/vista) and [windows-7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) and don't let anyone tag with the generic "windows"

Comment: Why to not just use ``windows-os`` and ``window-management``?

Comment: I don't have major objections to [tag:windows-os] - but there's no need to get people to tag windows-os and also tag vista - the former tag is just redundant.

Comment: I see, it's realy better use just the windows version as a tag, nice. +1

Comment: Does AU have so many Windows-related question that there's a need to distinguish between Windows versions? On U&L we just have the one [windows](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag and we've never felt the need to split. Version tags should only be used if the issue is specific to that version (e.g. don't use the `windows-vista` tag if XP or 7 have the same issue), are all the questions with these tags really specific?

Comment: @Gilles U&L has 44 windows questions. We have 118 tagged Windows 7 alone. People like being specific, might as well let them. (And in this case it's a handy way to get rid of the ambiguous plain 'windows')

Answer (score 2):

Use [windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows) for all issues related to interoperability with Microsoft Windows. (That's what we do on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), where the problematic is the same.)

I don't think it's a good idea to have a completely different meaning for the same tag. I recommend `window-NOUN` tags, such as [window-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window-management). There's even [window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/window) ([U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window)), which I consider a good name in principle but a bad name in practice because of the potential for confusion. (`echo "think of a better name for the window tag" >>TODO`)