# What is the purpose of two topics in one tag: windows

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the proper usage of the windows tag?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/188/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-the-windows-tag)

I am curious.  Why does the [windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag cover both the Windows OS as well as application windows?  shouldn't those be two separate tags, i.e. `windows-os` and `application-windows` or something?

*** EDIT ***

Also, does this still apply? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/188/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-the-windows-tag

In my opinion, it does not, because you should ***never*** be grouping application windows and the windows os in the same tag

*EDIT2*
Can a moderator or someone please pitch in on this thread?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with that...a Windows tag isn't the same as a windows app tag, they're completely different sets of information that tie into each other...